# Site collection lock status returns empty value

Tags: sharepoint-server, site, 2019, collection

Hoping someone can help out with this issue on SP19 on premise.

If I run the following on certain site collections, I get an empty value returned

Get-SPSite "" | Select ReadOnly,Readlocked,WriteLocked

[image]

On other site collections I get an expected return

[image]

I have ran the following and can see the changes being made via Central Admin

1. Set-SPSite -identity "Site name" –lockstate "ReadOnly"
2. Set-SPSite -identity "Site name" –lockstate "Unlock"

But upon checking the state via Powershell I still see empty values.  I have checked the database and this was in a 'Normal' state.

So everything looks to be working correctly other than the empty values being returned, yet when running any PS that checks the lock status I get "The current site collection is locked" message.

Is there any way this can be corrected?

Thanks for any assistance in advance.

Comment: maybe try to close the PowerShell console and re open it. make sure account has permission on the DB ( account running powershell).

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP, much appreciated.   I ran the same commands as Farm Admin and got a return.  I added Sharepoint account to Collection Administrators and it now returns the values I was looking for.  Cannot thank you enough.  Now how do I mark your reply as helpful or as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a permission issue, Could you please make sure that Account running the powershell command should have correct permission.

- Site collection Admin / Policy of Web app level
- If farm admin account then DBO on the content database.